# WinDBG w3wp.exe x Crash dump WRONG_SYMBOLS

Tags: asp.net-mvc, clr, windbg

I am running an Asp MVC application using in IIS 6 on a windows 2003 32 bit server.

I recently updated the application from .net 3.5 to .net 4.0 and started getting application pool restarts.

The event id's are 1009 and 1011 which led me to attach adplus to the process and try analyze the dumps using Windbg.

I have 4 FullDumps from when the application pool restarts happened but i am having trouble understanding what is happening.

There seems to be wrong symbols loaded for CLR

I have run 
    `.sympath srv*c:\Symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

which does seem to have brought a CLR.pdb file down to my C:\symbols folder

`EDIT` i have also run `symfix` and `.reload`

`!symnoisy` hasn't enlightened me either

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

```
.....
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for ntdll.dll - 
*** ERROR: Symbol file could not be found.  Defaulted to export symbols for clr.dll - 



FAULTING_IP: 
+0
00000000 ??              ???

EXCEPTION_RECORD:  ffffffff -- (.exr 0xffffffffffffffff)
ExceptionAddress: 00000000
   ExceptionCode: 80000003 (Break instruction exception)
  ExceptionFlags: 00000000
NumberParameters: 0

CONTEXT:  00000000 -- (.cxr 0x0;r)
eax=000000c0 ebx=00000000 ecx=000fbcd4 edx=000000e0 esi=00000304 edi=00000000
eip=7c82847c esp=1a6afd30 ebp=1a6afda0 iopl=0         nv up ei pl zr na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000246
ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet:
7c82847c c3              ret

FAULTING_THREAD:  00002aec

DEFAULT_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

PROCESS_NAME:  w3wp.exe

ERROR_CODE: (NTSTATUS) 0x80000003 - {EXCEPTION}  Breakpoint  A breakpoint has been reached.

EXCEPTION_CODE: (HRESULT) 0x80000003 (2147483651) - One or more arguments are invalid

NTGLOBALFLAG:  0

APPLICATION_VERIFIER_FLAGS:  0

APP:  w3wp.exe

ANALYSIS_VERSION: 6.3.9600.17029 (debuggers(dbg).140219-1702) x86fre

MANAGED_STACK: !dumpstack -EE
No export dumpstack found

PRIMARY_PROBLEM_CLASS:  WRONG_SYMBOLS

BUGCHECK_STR:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS

LAST_CONTROL_TRANSFER:  from 7c827b99 to 7c82847c

STACK_TEXT:  
1a6afd2c 7c827b99 77e61d1e 00000304 00000000 ntdll!KiFastSystemCallRet
1a6afd30 77e61d1e 00000304 00000000 00000000 ntdll!NtWaitForSingleObject+0xc
1a6afda0 791a1030 00000304 ffffffff 00000000 kernel32!WaitForSingleObjectEx+0xac
1a6afdd4 791a1071 00000304 ffffffff 00000000 clr!CLREvent::CreateManualEvent+0xf6
1a6afe24 7919d3e8 00000000 1d79f859 00000002 clr!CLREvent::CreateManualEvent+0x137
1a6afe64 7919d409 ffffffff 00000000 00000000 clr!CLREvent::WaitEx+0x126
1a6afe78 791e95ba ffffffff 00000000 00000000 clr!CLREvent::Wait+0x19
1a6afea8 792498cb 77e61a60 77e69468 ffffffff clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_function+0x62
1a6affb8 77e6482f 000fb840 00000000 00000000 clr!SVR::gc_heap::gc_thread_stub+0x7e
1a6affec 00000000 79249879 000fb840 00000000 kernel32!BaseThreadStart+0x34


STACK_COMMAND:  ~0s; .ecxr ; kb

FOLLOWUP_IP: 
clr!CLREvent::CreateManualEvent+f6
791a1030 8bf0            mov     esi,eax

SYMBOL_STACK_INDEX:  3

SYMBOL_NAME:  clr!CLREvent::CreateManualEvent+f6

FOLLOWUP_NAME:  MachineOwner

MODULE_NAME: clr

IMAGE_NAME:  clr.dll

DEBUG_FLR_IMAGE_TIMESTAMP:  4ba1d9ef

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  WRONG_SYMBOLS_80000003_clr.dll!CLREvent::CreateManualEvent

BUCKET_ID:  APPLICATION_FAULT_WRONG_SYMBOLS_clr!CLREvent::CreateManualEvent+f6

ANALYSIS_SOURCE:  UM

FAILURE_ID_HASH_STRING:  um:wrong_symbols_80000003_clr.dll!clrevent::createmanualevent

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {74ed651f-867a-9afc-f754-50babe161dea}

Followup: MachineOwner
```

`EDIT`

`.symfix
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: 
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols
DBGHELP: Symbol Search Path: cache*;SRV*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols`

```
.reload
................................................................
................................................................
...............................
Loading unloaded module list
.....
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\ntdll.pdb\D1FCA12451E64381B7879FA580BA7E582\ntdll.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\ntdll.pdb\D1FCA12451E64381B7879FA580BA7E582\ntdll.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: ntdll - public symbols  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\ntdll.pdb\D1FCA12451E64381B7879FA580BA7E582\ntdll.pdb

!analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Exception Analysis                                   *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\kernel32.pdb\BE496DC9472F4438B080C70594D8F9CC2\kernel32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\kernel32.pdb\BE496DC9472F4438B080C70594D8F9CC2\kernel32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: kernel32 - public symbols          C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\kernel32.pdb\BE496DC9472F4438B080C70594D8F9CC2\kernel32.pdb
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\clr.pdb\C58C9AF63E5D49A8BE0DBA9C5E0093BE2\clr.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\clr.pdb\C58C9AF63E5D49A8BE0DBA9C5E0093BE2\clr.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: clr - public symbols  
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\clr.pdb\C58C9AF63E5D49A8BE0DBA9C5E0093BE2\clr.pdb
SYMSRV:  WinInet Interface using proxy server: serv3906:8080
SYMSRV:  WinInet Interface using proxy server: serv3906:8080
SYMSRV:  File: sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll
SYMSRV:  File: sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll/4BA1D9EF66f000/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll/4BA1D9EF66f000/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll/4BA1D9EF66f000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  Get File Path: /download/symbols/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll/4BA1D9EF66f000/file.ptr
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Notifies the client application that a proxy has been detected.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Connecting to the Server: http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully connected to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Sending the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully sent the information request to the server.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Waiting for the server to respond to a request.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully received a response from the server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Closing the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  Successfully closed the connection to the Server.
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll/4BA1D9EF66f000/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll not found
SYMSRV:  http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll/4BA1D9EF66f000/sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll\4BA1D9EF66f000\sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll not found
SYMSRV:  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll\4BA1D9EF66f000\sos_x86_x86_4.0.30319.1.dll not found
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorlib.pdb\A21F40D38EAB4B64B449E50DE8F5A3431\mscorlib.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorlib.pdb\A21F40D38EAB4B64B449E50DE8F5A3431\mscorlib.pdb already cached *** WARNING: Unable to verify checksum for mscorlib.ni.dll
DBGHELP: mscorlib_ni - public symbols  
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\mscorlib.pdb\A21F40D38EAB4B64B449E50DE8F5A3431\mscorlib.pdb
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.pdb\B29B53A483EA4F5DAF2BF0FB1A4E7DB92\user32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.pdb\B29B53A483EA4F5DAF2BF0FB1A4E7DB92\user32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: user32 - public symbols  
  C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\user32.pdb\B29B53A483EA4F5DAF2BF0FB1A4E7DB92\user32.pdb
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.pdb\11E5E66EC6794BFDA9E7F5B1F00498AA2\ole32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.pdb\11E5E66EC6794BFDA9E7F5B1F00498AA2\ole32.pdb already cached
DBGHELP: ole32 - public symbols  
    C:\Program Files\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\sym\ole32.pdb\11E5E66EC6794BFDA9E7F5B1F00498AA2\ole32.pdb
GetUrlPageData2 (WinHttp) failed: 12007.
```

Comment: Do you see `Symbol search path is: *** Invalid ***` at the top when you load a dump file?  Try running `.symfix` to fix your symbols path, then `.reload` to reload symbols

Comment: Sorry Patrick i forgot to mention that. i have ran `.symfix` and `.reload` after i set the symbol path

Comment: Please post the full symbol loading trace after you run ```!sym noisy```, ```.symfix```, and ```.reload```.

Comment: Thanks Sasha.I have added in the output from !sym noisy, .symfix .reload followed by !analyze -v